# JEE sessions for a JavaScript front end hosted on a different server

Tags: java, ajax, session-cookies, backend, session-state

I am having trouble structuring my Java JEE backend to handle sessions (JEE servlets served with tomcat).

My front end is on another server that does not have Java, only html and JavaScript. The JavaScript uses ajax to post a username and password to the back end server which will create a session:

```
   session = request.getSession();
   session.setAttribute("email", email);
   session.setAttribute("auth", "1");
```

When the front end contacts the back end via javascript again after authentication, Java can't find the created session. Here is how I am looking for sessions after auth is set to 1:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String auth = (String) session.getAttribute("auth");
if (auth == null || !auth.equals("1")) {
   session.invalidate();// destroy any session that they may have
   System.out.println("Invalid Session");
   JsonGenerator gen = Json.createGenerator(response.getWriter());
   gen.writeStartObject().write("status", "expired").writeNull("data")
   .write("message", "Your session has expired").writeEnd();
   gen.close();
   return;            
}
```

Everything works fine when both the front end and back end are hosted on the same server with the same domain name. But not when the front end and back end are on separate servers with different domain names. How should I structure this so that Java can check if auth==1 when the front end contacts it?

Here is how I am contacting the back end server with Ajax:

```
  post_url = 'http://backend.anotherserver.com/api/datapoint'
  $.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    timeout: 10000,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
    if (json.status == 'success' && json.data) {
      // do something
    }
  })
```

The front end and back end have different domain names. After I get one front end working, I will create a second front end with a different domain name, and a third, fourth etc. They will all use the same back end and all the front ends need to be able to authenticate with the backend. I do not want to use an oauth server, that is too much for me to handle right now.

Comment: Am not sure if I getting you right. Do you have the same application running on different front-end servers with different domain names? Like for instance you have the same TODO list application running on 3 different front-end servers and your users are supposed to be using like www.mytodo1.com, www.mytodo2.com and www.mytodo3.com. These front-end servers will inturn hit the backend tomcat server backend.mytodo.com?

Comment: Yes Zapping that is correct. The front ends are mytodo1 mytodo2 and mytodo3, they are on different servers than mytodo. If I created a front end & backend that are both called mytodo, in the same java webapp on the same machine hosted by Tomcat then it works fine. But when separating the front and back end, sessions do not work

Comment: I think I am still not getting the purpose. Is it for load balancing your application that you have this?

Comment: White labeling, load balancing, separation of front and back end code. However, the backend server does have a copy of the front end code served up by Tomcat just for testing. The backend code is basically just an API. The front end is html and javascript that contacts the api.

Answer (score 0):

If load balancing is your requirement then I think you should review your server architecture. The frontend files i.e HTML, Javascript and images all gets downloaded to the client machine and that is where the actual execution of these file take place. If you have multiple servers for just HTML and Javascript then its an overkill of resource because these servers will only serve as a means for downloading the HTML and Javascript files. In case if you need to provide multiple source of download for your frontend files then you could go for CDN servers and the frontend contents can be downloaded from these sources.

The real action always takes place in the Tomcat server where all the Ajax calls from the client machine comes and converge, where the execution of backend code and processing of backend data takes place in the server machine. So you should be thinking of providing Tomcat cluster servers for handling the load instead. Then make the session sticky on these Tomcat clusters. So that session mixup does not happen between your frontend users requests. Session storage is unique to a domain or subdomain. Hence its not normally possible to share session between mulitple domains or subdomains. If you have clustered Tomcat servers then sticky session will help you avoid this issue. Then naturally have a load balancer with reverse proxy for white labeling.

Separation of frontend and backend code actually needs to be implemented by good coding artechture rather that providing different servers for js and backend tomcat files. If you dont have a good coding structure then even if you have different servers for js and backend files you can end up with codes crossing over from or between frontend and backend.